# SSIS Read date field from excel as string

Tags: sql, excel, ssis

I have an excel sheet with a column which is initially date format but there are lots of incorrect data which is not date format in this column. I want to read it into SQL server table then I could run some queries to correct the date. But I can not read the data, I have lots of trouble in conversion. I used 'Data conversion', 'Derived column', 'Advanced Editor', 'Input and Output properties' and lots of other things. My question is how I can read all these data as string not date format. However, I cannot have any change on the excel sheet. for sample, these are some data of this date format excel column.

```
2-May-57 
9-Apr-01 
22/05/1969 
1958/july/ 
Feb 7/81 
###################################################### 
dd/mm/yyyy 
6-Mar-79 
Jerse 
79-Mar-01 
80-1-01
```

I can change the field format of SQL server fortunately.
Thanks in advanced.

Comment: I cannot change the excel file as data is being entering into it daily by users. However, the same problem with .csv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have much experience with SSIS, just occasionally importing into SQL Server from Excel.  But when I read Excel files using .NET, I make a connection something like this.

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=c:\myFolder\myExcel2007file.xlsx;
Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1";

The important part above when it comes to reading Excel dates as strings is the "IMEX=1" part.  This keeps Excel from attempting to determine the data type.

I don't know if that's something you can apply with SSIS.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I add IMEX=1 in the connection string and it worked!! :)